# Sending AT cmd to BLE OBDII device

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, at-command, obd-ii, lightblue

I am building an app but I wanted to test the device before start coding.

The device that  I am using is veepeak BLE OBDII. I can connect to it using other popular apps with no issue e.g. CarScanner.

When using LightBlue app (BLE testing app), I can connect & see write and notify services/chars but when sending any AT command e.g. "**ATZ \r**" I always get "**?**" response.

Comment: Is the `?` representing an unprintable ascii byte value? Does the LightBlue app show you the raw bytes also?

Comment: @ukBaz yes, it can show utf-8 or binary or hex values. I also can send "ATZ \r"using binary or Hex "0x41545A205C72".
"?" means the device did not recognize the AT command.

Comment: Is that hex value correct? Should it not be `0x4154205a` and if you need to put the line ending then add `0x0d` so it would be `0x4154205a0d`?

Comment: @ukBaz Thank you! It worked. I should have known but I am an idiot.
The issue was in the line ending 0x0d. The first part was correct though. It can be written with or without space ATZ 0x41545A or AT Z 0x4154205A